# Facebook authentication for both mobile & web app in Cakephp

Tags: facebook, cakephp-2.0

Can anyone help me to overcome this hurdle..

### My Situation:

I have a webapp (Facebook app) in cakephp, which will b accessed only after Facebook authentication(Its working cool).

& now I have a mobile app & which will work on restapi, I want the same above webapp code to be served as RestApi.

Now I'm able to do authentication for mobile app with facebook, I need to authenticate my webapp which will server as rest api(unless I cannot use the code inside the app)..

### Requirement:

I have access_token & user_id with me sent by facebook to my mobile after successful login, & How can i authenticate my web app with these two..??

Can anyone look into this & help me to comeout..!!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Facebook data from inside CakePHP you have to send the access_token & user_id to CakePHP. You probably should narrow down your problem to a specific error or method that fails, here it's not really clear where your problem lies.

Comment: My WebAPP use FB for authentication.
& I have AccessToken & userid by someother means(I logged into my mobile app & got those), So now how can I Authenticate my WebAPP with these things, without using FB SDK..??